# The Intel RealSense R200 camera is not detected by the Turtlebot3 (Waffle)

Tags: ros, 3d-slam, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to do 3D SLAM using the R200 camera and Turtlebot3 Waffle.  I installed the Intel® RealSense™ package following the steps given in http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/appendix_realsense/#installation

When I ran

```
roslaunch realsense_camera r200_nodelet_rgbd.launch
```

I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1530659146.559707562]: /camera/driver - No cameras detected!
```

The camera was connected to Netmate USB 3.0 (4 port) hub. I tried connecting it directly but I am still getting the same error. Some additional information are:

I am not running inside a VM. The PC and OS specs are:

- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l
- 4.13.0-45-generic
- 64-bit machine

Is the camera recognized on some another platform? I didn't try this particular camera with another device other than the Turtlebot I have.

I am using the short USB cable provided with the camera device.

In [here](http://wiki.ros.org/librealsense) under title **Installation Troubleshooting** this particular error is mentioned. But as far as I understood, the solution provided applies to the case where the camera is connected to a PC not a Turtlebot, hence I didn't try the provided solution.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296148/the-intel-realsense-r200-camera-is-not-detected-by-the-turtlebot3-(waffle)/) by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-07-03**:
I suggest following **Installation Troubleshooting** in ROS WiKi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to solve this problem. The issue was to do with the permissions given to the user by the system admin. I asked the lab manager (who has sudo access) to give permission to my user ID to access the git cloned packages. Then I repeated these steps inside the second workspace that I created inside the Turtlebot.

```
$ cd catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense.git
$ cd realsense
$ git checkout 1.8.0
$ cd catkin_ws && catkin_make -j2
```

and the camera started working. Hope this helps anyone else who has the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) with karma: 71 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0